# Generate Random maps data in google maps like format using Python

Tags: python, google-maps, random, package, gis

How can I generate random data in google maps like format i.e. 29.299332, 52.892959?

Do you prefer any package for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a pair of random numbers between 0 and 90 degrees, why not just use the random package?

```
import random
print([random.random()*90, random.random()*90]) #[34.050498339418986, 5.622759330528135]
```